# Azure Databricks, cannot read comma separated CSV file with nested lists

Tags: csv, apache-spark, databricks

I have one quite big comma delimited CSV file(12GB). I have 4 columns, 1 of them contains nested lists with jsons. I can create a connection from Excel and it reads it correctly(despite the fact that I have some nested lists there, which means more commas). However, when I try to do it via spark, it gets sliced on every occurence of comma, which creates a lot of mess.

Ok, so I have tried to provide a schema. Apparently CSV doesn't support array type, so I cannot do it so easily. I can define schema with string instead of an Array but then my last column looks like this:

[image]

So, I get everything preeceding the first comma, rest is gone.

I have tried to read it as RDD with sc.textFile but then json structures get broken.

I am trying to write a function that would fix my jsons but it's getting quite frustrating so I have thought that maybe there is some simpler way?

I know it may be a dumb question but I just don't really see why something that is so easy in Excel would be so complicated in spark?

Thank you for any advice!

EDIT
excel:
[image]

spark:
[image]

Same with schema defined like that:

```
user_schema = StructType([
    StructField("businessID", StringType(), True), 
    StructField("vid", StringType(), True),
    StructField("company_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("financial_statements", StringType(), True)
])
```

I have also tried to change the file to parquet using ADF to catch the schema but it doesn't work either. Even though I have provided one from sample.
ADF:
[image]

Comment: Please post code of what you've tried. And have you tried loading csv with option?https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#manually-specifying-options

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer! I have tried that but it still gives me the same result(please see the screenshot attached).

Answer (score 0):

Try `[` as the `option`

```
val schema = StructType(
  Seq(
    StructField("businessID", StringType),
    StructField("vid", StringType),
    StructField("company_name", StringType),
    StructField("financial_statements", StringType),
  ),
)

val df = spark.read
  .schema(schema)
  .format("csv")
  .option("quote", "[")
  .load(path)

val jsonSchema = StructType(
  Seq(
    StructField("key1", StringType),
    StructField("key2", IntegerType),
    StructField("key3", BooleanType),
  ),
)

val dfClean = df.withColumn("financial_statements_json", from_json($"financial_statements", jsonSchema))

dfClean.printSchema()
dfClean.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------+---+------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|businessID|vid|company_name|financial_statements                       |financial_statements_json|
+----------+---+------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|1         |A  |AAA         |{"key1": "va1", "key2": 123, "key3": true}]|[va1, 123, true]         |
+----------+---+------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
```